# Php code Parse error: syntax error, unexpected

Tags: php

I would like to make a link for this query

Here is my code

```
$getfood = "<a href="./student.php?id=">" . $food['clickid'] . "</a>" $food['clickid'];
```

I get error: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '/'`

How to write the code in proper way..

It should be like `<a href="./student.php?id=33">33</a> 33`

Comment: [The Great Escapism (Or: What You Need To Know To Work With Text Within Text)](http://kunststube.net/escapism/)

Comment: Thanks @deceze i found a good solution from user4035.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "It should be like `<a href="./student.php?id=33">33</a> 33`"

Here is the code:

```
<?php
$food = array("clickid" => 33);
$getfood = "<a href=\"./student.php?id=" .
    $food['clickid'] . "\">". $food['clickid'] . "</a> " . $food['clickid'];
print $getfood;
```

Prints:

`<a href="./student.php?id=33">33</a> 33`

Mind, that I escaped the quotes and concatenated every piece of string with a dot.

Comment: I spend almost 2 hours. This works great. Now you are a genius and thank you very much!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape your double quote characters.

```
$getfood = "<a href=\"./student.php?id=\">" . $food['clickid'] . "</a>" . $food['clickid'];
```

Comment: Hi thank you!.. please look at @user4035 for the correct one.